# Maybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, fastlane, bitrise

I have an already working react-native project, with `bitrise` and `fastlane` deploy also configured.
I used to build the app with the `xcode 12.5` version, but with the new apple updates, it was necessary to upgrade the xcode version, because the app started not to build with this xcode version. So I changed the `bitrise` stack to the same used on my local machine `(xcode 13.2.1 on OSX BigSur)`.

But now, the build is failing with this message:

```
[14:04:40]: Exit status: 65
[14:04:40]: 
[14:04:40]: Maybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode
[14:04:40]: Found multiple versions of Xcode in '/Applications/'
[14:04:40]: Make sure you selected the right version for your project
[14:04:40]: This build process was executed using '/Applications/Xcode-13.2.1.app'
[14:04:40]: If you want to update your Xcode path, either
[14:04:40]: 
[14:04:40]: - Specify the Xcode version in your Fastfile
[14:04:40]: ▸ xcversion(version: "8.1") # Selects Xcode 8.1.0
[14:04:40]: 
[14:04:40]: - Specify an absolute path to your Xcode installation in your Fastfile
[14:04:40]: ▸ xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode8.app"
[14:04:40]: 
[14:04:40]: - Manually update the path using
[14:04:40]: ▸ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
[14:04:40]:
```

And after sometime researching, I found the `xcversion` plugin for fastlane, to select the properly `xcode` version. And added the following line to my `Fastfile`

```
...
xcversion(version: "13.2.1")
...
```

And added the following `gem` to my `Gemfile`

```
...
gem "xcode-install"
...
```

But the same error happens, even with the changes above. Does anyone already faced this problem?

Comment: Is there any additional information / error message before the `[14:04:40]: Exit status: 65`?

Comment: Only these two information. Not related to the issue

❌  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I submitted a ticket to the bitrise support, and after some time they helped me to find a related issue about Xcode 13 that really fixed my issue. The issue is this one [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31733#issuecomment-931824830). Thanks everyone for the help.